# Moving the "flagging question" GUI around moves other elements on the page

Tags: bug, review-queues, triage, flag-dialog

When I view the "flagging question" UI in the Triage review queue (couldn't reproduce this outside of the review queues) and move the GUI around, some elements on the page shift around.

Can we fix this?

[image]

I'm seeing this in Chrome 67. I have the sidebar nav turned off.

Update: It looks like this only happens when I'm zoomed out a little and move the GUI to the bottom such that it escapes the page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen some specific notes that zoom isn't supported. I'm not sure if the updated layout will change that or not.

Comment: *Doctor, it hurts when I do this* ... then stop doing that ...

Comment: This is because the _scrollbar_ on your right edge appears to accomodate for the increased page height when you move the dialog down.

Comment: @Xufox Oh wow, I think that's all it is. I remember the element shifting being more "severe" than just everything moving to the left, but I can't reproduce this. Looks like you're right